# Batch processing using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've a array `jobs` in JavaScript and want to send to server side for some processing, and since it is a very large array, in order to avoid timeout, I slice into small pieces, e.g. `smallerJobs`

```
var chunk= 50;
for (var i=0; i<jobs.length; i+=size) {
    var smallerJobs = jobs.slice(i,i+size);

    $.post( "server.php", { jobs: smallerJobs })
      .done(function( data ) {
          // Show the server result to client
      });
    }
 }
```

The above code works, however, since `post` is async in JavaScript, instead of using `async: false`, how to make the above code run in sequential? i.e. in the same order as the array `jobs` and avoid `DOS` the server?

Answer (score 1):

You could run the next post query on success of the previous post query.
Turn your post call into a function where on success event it first does whatever you want with the data then calls the function recursively again with the next item.

something like:

```
function sequentialQuerying(jobArr, currJob){

    if(currJob == jobs.length){
        return;
    }else{
        var smallerJobs = jobArr.slice(currJob, currJob+size);
        $.post("server.php", {jobs: smallerJobs})
            .done(function(data){
                //do something with the data if you want
                sequentialQuerying(jobArr, currJob += size);
            });
    }
}
```